# autoit: what's the difference between inetget and inetread

Tags: autoit

I see there are two functions in autoit to download files from the internet: inetget and inetread.

What's the difference between the two? The only difference I see is that inetGet has more options and is therefore better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Inetget()` supports background download (your script will continue its work while your file will keep downloading) and returns you a handle you can use with `Inetgetinfo()`. `Inetread` can do nothing of this.

Read the manual carefully, everything is described there. :)
By the way, AutoIT's doc is very good to me.

Comment: Autoit has amazing documentation, almost all basic questions can be answered there. If you're going to write anything in autoit, read through it all at least once.

Comment: I did read the docs. I meant for my question to really ask _why_ Inetget is simply superior. It always feels weird to me to have duplicated effort and purpose between two functions with no explanation as to why two functions serve the exact same purpose.

But you did answer the question I asked. As far as I can figure out, Inetread is something like the lower level function which inetget is a wrapper around.

Answer (score 2):

There IS a big difference! InetRead() directly returns the downloaded string, so you can assign it to variable while InetGet needs a filename parameter to store into, so if you periodically get some data it may be better to use inetread instead to prevent hdd usage.